# How to convert multiple .VTT segments to one single .VTT file or subtitle file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I have a list of .VTT segments from a bunch of URLs for a stream looking like these (the total amount of segments is much higher):

```
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_3.vtt
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_2.vtt
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_1.vtt
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_0.vtt
```

Is there a way to automatically convert all the segments into one text file without having to do it manually?

Comment: I updated my answer, can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2):

We may create `playlist.m3u8` [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) playlist file, and pass it as input to ffmpeg:

Create `playlist.m3u8` text file with your URLs segments:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:0
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:1,
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_0.vtt
#EXTINF:1,
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_1.vtt
#EXTINF:1,
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_2.vtt
#EXTINF:1,
https://drod24s.akamaized.net/all/clear/none/d9/5e625421a95a611504451ed9/00922001400/subtitles/Foreign_HardOfHearing-17241006-627dc540-cc6e-44dc-a003-09ea95deff85/segment_3.vtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

---

Execute the following FFmpeg command for downloading and merging the VVT segements:

`ffmpeg -y -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -allowed_extensions ALL -i playlist.m3u8 -c copy -f webvtt merged_segments.vvt`

---

Note:
The solution was tested using `ffmpeg version 5.1.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev` in Windows 10.

Comment: In the 4 source files, the timings follow each other. That is to say: the timing of the next one starts where the previous one left off. In this solution, the timings are modified and no longer follow each other.

Comment: @Alain1A45 Thank you for letting me know that my solution is not working. It looks like there is a bug in concat demuxer when merging subtitle files. Can you please check my updated answer?

Comment: Tested too. Very good solution. Clever.

Comment: I created some python scrips to do the job too if you want them, takes a bit of manual work but it's minimal and can combine many segments